# Bind an array of structures to DataGrid and auto generate columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, struct

I am trying to develop a simple testing application that displays a DataGrid comprised of an array of structures.  I have roughly 20 web services that all return arrays of structures, each of a different type of structure, that I would like to bind to the datagrid to verify the data is accurate.

What is the easiest way to generically bind all the columns for each of the various types of structures into the same DataGrid so that it is easy to toggle from one method to the other on the fly?  I know this would be trivial if the structures were classes with public properties, unfortunately, I am stuck with these structs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a view model to receive the structs from web services and converts them to classes (These you have to define for each struct). Define `DataTemplate`s for each of your classes in `DataGrid.Resources`.